# Wordpress custom search with more than one post type

Tags: php, wordpress

In WordPress when you want to limit your search to a specific post type you add the following line to your search form `<input type="hidden" value="product" name="post_type" />` where value contains the name of the post type. What if you want to search with two post types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do this by adding the following function in the functions.php file

```
function searchfilter($query) {

if ($query->is_search && !is_admin() ) {
    $query->set('post_type',array('post_type_1','post_type_2'));
}
```

return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts','searchfilter');

Notice the line `$query->set('post_type',array('post_type_1','post_type_2'));`

This is where I passed the post types as arguments

Comment: Great Answer Buddy!